# Highcharts dataGrouping approximation column point color based on column value?

Tags: highcharts

How can I have approximated columns to be colored based on column value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging and some messages with Highcharts support, I finally got in shape.

To callback function after Highcharts complete:

```
}, function(chart) { // on complete

    // Color approximated columns by value
    var series = chart.series[0];
    delete series.pointAttr.hover.fill;
    delete series.pointAttr[''].fill;
    // There are only values 0-5 as integers in this data series
    var colors = { 0: '#fff',  1: '#999', 2: '#777', 3: '#555', 4: '#333' };
    for (var i = 0; i < series.points.length; i++) {
        series.points[i].graphic.attr("fill", colors[ series.points[i].y ] );
    }
});
```

Event to xAxis for recoloring after zoom events:

```
xAxis : [ {
    events: {
        afterSetExtremes: function(event){
            // Color approximated columns by value, again after zoom
            var chart = angular.element('#presence-chart').highcharts();
            var series = chart.series[0];
            delete series.pointAttr.hover.fill;
            delete series.pointAttr[''].fill;
            var colors = { 0: '#fff',  1: '#50117a', 2: '#7631a0', 3: '#c171ed', 4: '#72accf' };
            for (var i = 0; i < series.points.length; i++) {
                series.points[i].graphic.attr("fill", colors[ series.points[i].y ] );
            }
        }
    }
} ],
```

Someone could fill in here how to get hover colors as if you comment out "delete series.pointAttr[''].fill;" then after hover the bar stays with that hover color?